Trouble understanding Errorlog - HTTP Error 500
My Website is showing HTTP Error 500. It started immediately I installed OJS. The admin page is working fine but the frontend is showing the HTTP Error.
I tried to check the errorlog in My CPanel but I do not know what to do specifically with the error message. I cannot decipher what it wants me to do in order to rectify the issue. The Error message is supplied below:
[13-Jun-2024 04:13:06 America/New_York] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getOption() on null in /home/nbabauch/gjah.gamjiinstitute.org/cache/t_compile/00a0a0910209607cb33eb0fe6474f30ed7399ed7^e64e579388e5615e11e939b12134d6ae8679eba6_0.app.frontendpagesindexJournal.tpl.php:36
Stack trace:
#0 /home/nbabauch/gjah.gamjiinstitute.org/lib/pkp/lib/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_template_resource_base.php(123): content_6669fb03d9d7b0_60046000(Object(Smarty_Internal_Template))
#1 /home/nbabauch/gjah.gamjiinstitute.org/lib/pkp/lib/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_template_compiled.php(114): Smarty_Template_Resource_Base->getRenderedTemplateCode(Object(Smarty_Internal_Template))
#2 /home/nbabauch/gjah.gamjiinstitute.org/lib/pkp/lib/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_template.php(217): Smarty_Template_Compiled->render(Object(Smarty_Internal_Template))
#3 /home/nbabauch/gjah.gamjiinstitute.org/lib/pkp/lib/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php(238): Smarty_Internal_Template->render(false, 1)
#4 /home/nbabauch/gjah.gamjiinstitute.org/lib/pkp/lib/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php(134): Smarty_Internal_TemplateBase->_execute(Object(Smarty_Internal_Template), NULL, '00a0a0910209607...', NULL, 1)
#5 /home/nbabauch/gjah.gamjiinstitute.org/lib/pkp/classes/template/PKPTemplateManager.php(1368): Smarty_Internal_TemplateBase->display('frontend/pages/...', NULL, '00a0a0910209607...', NULL)
#6 /home/nbabauch/gjah.gamjiinstitute.org/pages/index/IndexHandler.php(83): PKP\template\PKPTemplateManager->display('frontend/pages/...')
#7 [internal function]: APP\pages\index\IndexHandler->index(Array, Object(APP\core\Request))
#8 /home/nbabauch/gjah.gamjiinstitute.org/lib/pkp/classes/core/PKPRouter.php(334): call_user_func(Array, Array, Object(APP\core\Request))
#9 /home/nbabauch/gjah.gamjiinstitute.org/lib/pkp/classes/core/PKPPageRouter.php(277): PKP\core\PKPRouter->_authorizeInitializeAndCallRequest(Array, Object(APP\core\Request), Array, false)
#10 /home/nbabauch/gjah.gamjiinstitute.org/lib/pkp/classes/core/Dispatcher.php(165): PKP\core\PKPPageRouter->route(Object(APP\core\Request))
#11 /home/nbabauch/gjah.gamjiinstitute.org/lib/pkp/classes/core/PKPApplication.php(388): PKP\core\Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(APP\core\Request))
#12 /home/nbabauch/gjah.gamjiinstitute.org/index.php(21): PKP\core\PKPApplication->execute()
#13 {main}
thrown in /home/nbabauch/gjah.gamjiinstitute.org/cache/t_compile/00a0a0910209607cb33eb0fe6474f30ed7399ed7^e64e579388e5615e11e939b12134d6ae8679eba6_0.app.frontendpagesindexJournal.tpl.php on line 36
